# Notifications are not send while I'm receiving no error

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating a application but I'm stuck on the notification part. I want the android app to send a notification when I press on the button. I've done that by using HTTP request to Firebase but it is not sending the notification. It also does not give me a error. I followed a YouTube tutorial online but I couldn't contact the creator of the video and nobody in the comments section could help me.

```
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";   


public void sendMessage() {
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        mainObj.put("to:", "/topics/news");
        JSONObject notificationObj = new JSONObject();
        notificationObj.put("title", "any title");
        notificationObj.put("body", "any body");
        mainObj.put("notification",notificationObj);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                mainObj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "LADIES AND GENELTJEATMK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "ERROR E SAH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        ){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-Type", "text/json");
                header.put("authorization", "key=MYKEYSHOULDCOMEHERE");
                return header;
            }
        };

        mRequestQueue.add(request);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post "mainObj" as a string here?

Comment: What do you mean with as a string?

Comment: just print mainObj.toString and copy the request and paste here

Comment: D/myTag: {"to:":"\/topics\/news","notification":{"title":"any title","body":"any body"}}

Comment: "to:":"\/topics\/news" - this seems wrong to me , check this again

Comment: I've changed it to this but: {"to:":"topics\/news","notification":{"title":"any title","body":"any body"}}

Comment: Same problem again

Comment: use like this "to":"topics\/news" and let me know

Comment: It is like this right now: D/myTag: {"to":"\/topics\/news","notification":{"title":"any title","body":"any body"}}

Comment: Okay so I fixed it by changing "text/json"); to: "application/json"); , it is not going giving the onErrorResponse but its also not showing any notification